# Drawing a heatmap in R based on zipcodes only

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to draw a heatmap in R but my datafile is like this

```
Lat, Long, Zip, Zvalue
```

I basically need to interpolate between lat and long values and draw colors based on the zvalue

How can I do that in R

I eventually want to get something like this

[image]

Comment: If you have the latitude and longitude data then are the zip codes irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, I can use either zip codes or lat/long data

Comment: Are there any good solutions for this problem? The packages are rather complex... Did You solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `spatstat` is your friend!

http://www.spatstat.org/spatstat/

If your data is a set of events (like "a crime occurred at (x,y)" for many (x,y)), then you can use a kernel density estimate to generate your heat map. You can see an example here:

https://github.com/drewconway/WikiLeaks_Analysis/blob/master/density.r

specifically line 72.

If your z values are real values (which is probably the case reading your question) then you can use spatstat's `smooth` function which uses a Gaussian kernel to perform the interpolation and get back a set of pixels which have been generated by interpolating your data.

Alternatively, you can use the `akima` package (as recommended by the `spatstat` authors) for interpolation at locations you specify. It uses either linear or spline-based interpolation and seems pretty straightforward (though I've no experience with it!).

More generally what you're trying to do is often called "Kriging", and so you get lots of results if you hit up google for that. See e.g. the `gstat` and `geoR` packages.

Finally (and FTW) you can use Gaussian Processes to do the same sort of thing. This will actually give you a distribution over possible interpolations given your data. The R package `kernlab` has an implementation though I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Jeffrey Breen has done this type of plot using the ggplot2 and the zipcode packages: http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/cran-zipcode/

That should get you started

Comment: but it is not even a heatmap, at its best it is a Choropleth maps. I am wondering if there is any function/package that can do the interpolation automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the code of the ggplot case studies competition winner  [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Crime-in-Downtown-Houston%2C-Texas-%3A-Combining-ggplot2-and-Google-Maps)

The author used geom_tile to make a heatmap, the title of the graph is :  **Violent Crime Weather Map of Downtown Houston**