# How do I create a heat map in R using data with zip codes?

Tags: r, geospatial, heatmap

I hope you're doing well.

I currently have data from the US with values for magnitude and zip code. Similar to:

| Magnitude | Zip_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00001 |
| 2 | 00002 |

I would like to do two things with this data: create a map showing the number of responses by zip code and interpolate a heat map for magnitude across the country. Ideally, I would like to produce maps similar to:

An example from this thread, producing heat map over Geo locations in R

[image: An example from this thread, producing heat map over Geo locations in R]

[image: An example from this thread, producing heat map over Geo locations in R]

Is there any easy way to do this in R? Thank you so much.

I started using the choroplethrZip package, but I'm not sure how to use it. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing a heatmap in R based on zipcodes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885251/drawing-a-heatmap-in-r-based-on-zipcodes-only)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how I use `choroplethrZip` library.

The key point is that the value column must be called value, and the zip code column must be called "region". The zip code data must be character/string values that match the internal function source data.

> A data.frame with a column named "region" and a column named "value". Elements in the "region" column must exactly match how regions are named in the "region" column in ?zip.map.

```
#install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')
library(choroplethrZip)
water<-structure(list(region = c("32034", "32081", "32082", "32092", 
"32097", "32202", "32204", "32205", "32206", "32207", "32208", 
"32209", "32210", "32211", "32216", "32217", "32218", "32219", 
"32220", "32221", "32222", "32223", "32224", "32225", "32226", 
"32233", "32234", "32244", "32246", "32250", "32254", "32256", 
"32257", "32258", "32259", "32277"), value = c(284, 368, 337, 
338, 280, 247, 247, 260, 227, 253, 220, 244, 209, 309, 298, 270, 
256, 282, 267, 216, 156, 240, 283, 304, 242, 254, 180, 188, 301, 
301, 267, 334, 240, 240, 310, 258)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), 
class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

zip_choropleth(water, 
               zip_zoom = (water$region), 
               num_colors = 1, 
               title = "Jacksonville FL Area Water Hardness by Zip Code", 
               legend = "PPM")
```

[image: Jacksonville FL Area Water Hardness by Zip Code]

Data Source: https://www.jea.com/About/Water_Supply/Water_Hardness_Levels/